# How to load music files, from local app 'Files' to my own app. Swift

Tags: swift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piPYm.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrObk.jpg)

Hello. How can I load music files from local app 'Files' then I load my own app 'Player'. I tried to use FileManager but it doesn't help me.

I need that when I open my application, music files from the 'Files' application are automatically displayed there.

Comment: /Users/pavelmishanin/Desktop/Simulator Screen Shot - iPhone 11 - 2022-09-21 at 12.08.44.png

Comment: I hope this article will help you https://www.appcoda.com/files-app-integration/ . The idea is pretty straightforward. You create a folder with is accessible from Files app. Then will be able to read and write there your music files.